# k-means clustering with gamma distribution

Tags: matlab

i am working on mammograms.
I want to segment the mammograms using k-means clustering with gamma distribution
in matlab . 
Only applying k-means-clustering i know, but don't know how to implement it with gamma distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This paper describes a method for k-means clustering for gamma distributions:

[Gumaei, A., et. al "Breast segmentation using k-means algorithm with a mixture of gamma distributions," 2012.](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/mhussain/CADProject/CP6_Gumnai2012.pdf)

The crux of the method is that you need to update the cluster means to account for the gamma distribution. This equation is also given in the paper.